# How to prevent page scrolling if I am over iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scroll

I have iframe on my page. The iframe does not have more content than it's height but it does use mousewheel for zooming. When I mousewheel on main page it scrolls the main page, when I am over the iframe, it also scrolls the main page. I want iframe to use catch mousewheel events and prevent parent page to scroll.

```html
I want this page to be scrollable but when you are over the iframe page should not be scrollable

<br>
<iframe src="https://ghost.sk/bug/iframe-scroll-child.html"></iframe>
<br>

Here I try use scrolling="yes":<br>

<br>
<iframe src="https://ghost.sk/bug/iframe-scroll-child.html" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
<br>


<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
<br>More text to make page scrollable
```

Edit: I control both the main page and iframe and they are on the same domain.